# Legend of Drizzt - How may items per Hero Phase?

Tags: dnd-adventure-system

I didn't notice anything in the rulebook about how many items can be used in each player's Hero Phase.  Is it just 1, or are multiple items allowed to be used?

Comment: Could you maybe cite the rulebook about using items in the Hero Phase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use as many items as you like, as long as you follow the rules on the card. For example, if you have two *Potion of Healing*s you can use them both during your Hero Phase, but not during another player's turn. You may use a *Heavy Cloak* on the Villain Phase during your turn, or another player's turn. A *Flask of Oil* is used instead of attacking, so you can only use one on your turn.

From [the rulebook](https://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/LoD_Rulebook_EN.pdf):

> You can benefit from multiple Treasure cards in play that apply
>   to your Hero. For example, you can use both a Fortune and an
>   Item to increase the bonus to an attack roll.

"Multiple Treasure cards" includes using multiple Items (subject to the rules listed on them). However,

> The only exception to this rule applies to Items that provide
>   attack or defense bonuses. A Hero can gain only one attack
>   bonus and one defense bonus from Items at a time.

This exception means that you cannot use two [*Belt of Storm Giant Strength*](http://ddadventuresystem.wikia.com/wiki/Belt_of_Storm_Giant_Strength)s at the same time.